# Configuring jquery datatable with require.js and using with backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, datatable, requirejs

I want to use jquery dataTables plugin for one of my table which is dynamically generated using backbone.js

After exploring the options for configuring dataTable with require.js I came out with this solution

This is from my main.js file

```
require.config({
    baseUrl : 'js',
    paths: {
        jquery: '../../assets/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        underscore: '../../assets/js/libs/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: '../../assets/js/libs/backbone/backbone',
        dataTable : '../../assets/js/libs/jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js'
    },

    shim : {

        backbone : {
            deps : [ "underscore", "jquery" ],
            exports : "Backbone"
        },

        underscore : {
            exports : "_"
        },

        dataTable : {
            deps : ["jquery"],
            exports : "Datatable"
        }

    },

});
```

Running upto this configuration, applications works perfectly but after using this object in in my app.js breaks the normal flow of application

```
define([
        'jquery','underscore', 'backbone', 'router', 'dataTable'
        ], 

function($, _, Backbone, Router, Datatable) {

    var initialize = function() {

        // calls router.js's initialize() function
        Router.initialize();

    }

    return {
        initialize : initialize
    };

});
```

I get the following error in firebug

Error: Script error for: dataTable http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

and if i do not include dataTable in my app.js then i get

$(...).dataTable is not a function

Can someone help me in figuring out what's wrong here.

Answer (score 11):

Don't need to do shim in your requireJS config for the dataTables plugin since is already an AMD module, just change the key from `dataTable` to `datatables` in your paths definitions, the reason for this is that the AMD module for it is defined with that name, please take a look at the  source code [here](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables).

```
require.config({
    baseUrl : 'js',
    paths: {
        jquery: '../../assets/js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        underscore: '../../assets/js/libs/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: '../../assets/js/libs/backbone/backbone',
        datatables : '../../assets/js/libs/jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js'
    },

    shim : {

        backbone : {
            deps : [ "underscore", "jquery" ],
            exports : "Backbone"
        },

        underscore : {
            exports : "_"
        }

    },

});
```

Now when you import the datatables plugin the `$("selector").dataTable()` function will be available

```
define(['jquery','underscore', 'backbone', 'router', 'datatables'],     
function($, _, Backbone, Router) {

    var initialize = function() {

        // calls router.js's initialize() function
        Router.initialize();

    }

    return {
        initialize : initialize
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

dataTables (like jquery) is already AMD complient, remove it from your Shim configuration.

Comment: But how do i make it available on the page where i really need it!!!

Wherever i used it, i get dataTable is not a function error

Comment: @rjk did you manage to make it work? if so can you share how u did

Comment: @MarcelDjaman Ramon's answer worked for me. In short, the key of the datatables module inside paths object should be **exactly** 'datatables'.